# Shell script to read number of inputs and then store it as key value pair

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script where the i have to first read the number of inputs that i am going to pass to the script and then read as many inputs.

Example:

```
Enter the number of input arguments: 2
```

If i pass 2, then i have to get 2 pairs of inputs from user and store it as key value pair.

```
Enter Name: ABC
Enter Subject: Physics

Enter Name: BCD
Enter Subject: Chemistry
```

If i pass 3, then i have to get 3 pairs of input from user.

```
Enter the number of input arguments: 3

Enter Name: ABC
Enter Subject: Physics

Enter Name: ABC
Enter Subject: Chemistry

Enter Name: ABC
Enter Subject: Maths
```

Output should be like a key value pair.

Is there a way to achieve this shell script ?

What I tried so far:
I read the number of input pairs using read -r and using loop try to read as many name and subject. But not sure how to store each name and subject as key value pair.

```
printf "Enter number of input pairs:" 
read -r count
current_iter=0

until [ "current_iter" -ge ${count} ]
do
  printf "Enter Name:"
  read -r name
  printf "Enter Subject:"
  read -r subject
  current_iter=$((current_iter+1))
done
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using below. Please suggest if any better approach is there.

```
printf "Enter number of input pairs:" 
read -r count
current_iter=0 #counter for loop
delicate -A name_sub #array for key value pair

until [ "current_iter" -ge ${count} ]
do
  printf "Enter Name:"
  read -r name
  printf "Enter Subject:"
  read -r subject

  name_sub[${name}]=${subject}
  current_iter=$((current_iter+1))
done

for key in "${!name_sub[@]}"; do
    echo "Name is: $key and Subject is: ${name_sub[$key]}"
```